# Is having bike lanes safer than not having them?

Tags: bicycles, traffic

Is having bike lanes safer than not having them?

This [Globe and Mail](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-drive/culture/commuting/who-has-the-right-of-way-in-designated-bike-lanes/article34015444/) ("Canada's National News Paper") article discusses bike lanes and claims that when correctly applied they are safer.

Here are some media claims that they are:

https://www.popsci.com/protected-bike-lanes-safer-roads/

https://www.citylab.com/transportation/2019/06/protected-bike-lanes-safe-street-design-bicycle-road-safety/590722/

https://www.cycleto.ca/making-cycling-easy-protected-bike-lanes

This study claims that separated bike tracks are the safest:

http://cyclingincities.spph.ubc.ca/injuries/the-bice-study/

Bike lanes seem to be very popular with the local news media.  And they seem to find a lot of cyclists who think they are a brilliant idea. I'm challenging this claim on the basis of my everyday observations, in particular for cars turning right and thus crossing the bicycle lane.

Are bike lanes safer?

Comment: Bicycle lines come in different types. It's unlikely that the same degree of safety applies to all types.

Comment: @DJClayworth  Seems to me you just volunteered to elucidate the different types of bike lanes and how they affect safety.

Comment: The NY Post is an example of media that's *not* fond of them. Not sure if Toronto immediately compares to NYC ...

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I went to remove the unnecessarily detailed anecdote that is distracting from the general claim, but then I was left with a one line question!

Comment: [Try this one:](https://thenarwhal.ca/why-new-bike-lanes-are-good-everyone-yes-even-drivers/)   *"Not only do bike lanes make the roads safer for cyclists, but they also reduce crashes and near-misses between cars."* Claims they're even safer for cars too.

Comment: When you find a notable claim from one of your sources, you should quote it in the question. I cannot see anywhere that the Globe and Mail say they are safer.

Comment: Pop Sci claim that more cyclists mean safer roads for drivers and pedestrians. I cannot see where they claim bike lanes are safer for cyclists.

Comment: City Lab makes the same claim as Pop Sci.

Comment: Cycle Toronto say that separate bike lanes make cyclists less stressed which encourages cycling. I can see them make the claim it is safer.

Comment: I have edited out the personal anecdote - *one* specific situation is irrelevant to the question. Now relevant quotes from the links should be added, and then most of the comments here can be deleted.

Comment: Note that e.g. the popsci link references research that would be better as a link here. @puppetsock You still have some work to do ;-)

Comment: Apart from the notable claim i think OP should refine their answer to just canada or north america, Trafic rules vary wildly. For example in the netherlands cyclist are legaly protected so this is not nearly as much of a problem.

Comment: Traffic rules may vary widely, but the concept of bike lanes being safer is irrespective of laws.

Comment: @Borgh, I liked the bicycle lanes I saw in Amsterdam a few years ago.  But they are nothing like the nominal infrastructure that gets built in Canada.  The Dutch cyclists were _real_ cyclists, going fast and actually commuting somewhere.  If a pedestrian should get too close or actually stand in a bike lane, they will be kicked or shouldered out of the way, and not gently or politely.  That behaviour would never be tolerated here.

Comment: @fred_dot_u yes, but for example in the netherlands a "bike lane" usually means a completely seperate piece of infrastructure with seperate trafic lights and no cars allowed. I know those make biking safer (by completly removing any interaction) but the question seams geared towards the american system where a "bike lane" just means a painted line on the road.

Answer (score 2):

Having taken a bicycle safety course, I can attest to part of the syllabus in which they explain why bicycle lanes are less safe than operating as another road user / vehicle operator. As a proponent of these courses, I operated in that manner and have personal experience for both methods. Bicycle lanes are unsafe compared to conventional road operations.

The problem is more with the road users (of all kinds) than with the infrastructure. People on bicycles are poorly trained to interact with other vehicles on the roadway, and people in motor vehicles who have not taken a bicycle safety course of the proper format are also ignorant of safe use of the roadway. Bicyclists are responsible to obey traffic control devices, including stop signs, traffic signals, road markings, etc. Motor vehicle operators have similar responsibilities.

You've referenced an intersection. This is the most common dangerous encounter for a bicyclist in the bike lane. The motor vehicle operators should have pulled into the bike lane prior to the intersection, signaling intent. Cyclists approaching the intersection with intent to continue straight through should have taken the main traffic lane.

This is part of what is taught in a bicycle safety course and it is effective and solves much of the problem you describe.

I became a certified instructor of this course and gave it up in short order.

Politicians and other administrative people like to present bike lanes as a panacea, but it's not that way at all.

As requested/required, references in the above answer represent my personal experience with the [CyclingSavvy](https://cyclingsavvy.org/mission/) program. Specific quoted material from the web site:

> **PEOPLE IN CARS**
>
> Most people want to do the right thing, but many drivers don’t know
>   the best way to interact with bicyclists: They don’t know our space
>   requirements; they often underestimate our speed; and sometimes they
>   overlook us.
>
> Most crashes caused by motorist mistakes can be avoided or prevented
>   by the bicyclist — often as simply and passively as riding in a more
>   visible position.
>
> Most drivers are willing to cooperate with a bicyclist who
>   communicates.
>
> Regardless of whether or not motorists believe bicyclists have the
>   right to control a lane, or understand why we need to, they will
>   change lanes to pass a lane-controlling bicyclist. That’s what
>   matters.
>
> Inattentive driving is a problem, but bicyclists can easily command
>   the attention of drivers — including those who are mildly distracted —
>   by being relevant and operating in their primary focus area.

Specific to bike lanes:

> **INFRASTRUCTURE**
>
> Bicycle-specific infrastructure is valuable for both access and
>   enjoyment, when designed properly and applied in an appropriate
>   context.
>
> Well-designed bicycle infrastructure is an asset to the community.
>
> Most types of bicycle-specific infrastructure, including bike lanes
>   and side paths, have contexts in which they work well, create access,
>   increase comfort and benefit bicyclists. Unfortunately, some of these
>   facilities can be very problematic when designed poorly or used in the
>   wrong context.

Comment: The rules for intersections vary widely.

Comment: It's a general question, I provided a general answer and the OP has done additional research useful to his question as a result.

Comment: *"The motor vehicle operators should have pulled into the bike lane prior to the intersection, signaling intent. Cyclists approaching the intersection with intent to continue straight through should have taken the main traffic lane."* That's not intuitive at all! No wonder people don't get it.

Comment: That's one aspect of the safety course that can be mentally challenging. For an untrained cyclist, it's "hazardous" to be in the traffic lane, yet the trained cyclist sees it as a legally permitted safety feature.

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: References added in recent edit.

Comment: @fredsbend, "_That's not intuitive at all!_".  Even worse, some people believe (and perhaps it's actually true in some jurisdictions), that the right-turning car should remain in the main lane and give right-of-way to bicycles that are going straight through in the lane to the right of them.

Comment: My own city has been going crazy over the last few years building "bicycle infrastructure".  It's great for publicity and photos, but in practice I seldom see them being used, at least not correctly.  People stand on them waiting for a bus, people walk on them or stand and have a conversation, garbage accumulates on them, etc.  And in many cases, the few bicycles I _do_see are going in the wrong direction.  Meanwhile, the sidewalk still has more bicycles on it than the designated path.  Not only are my taxes being wasted on this, the city pays for maintaining these paths throughout the winter.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think in many states, the general rule is that in the absence of designated paths, bicycles and pedestrians have right of way. But if a bike is on the road, they are subject to regular traffic rules. As for me, I'm a sidewalk cyclist. I don't relish the idea of competing with cars for road space.